# How to base64 encode php in this format?

Tags: php, function, base64, decode, encode

can you guide me how to base64 encode php by base64 decode below? I have php code that decodes base64 in below encoding way:

```
function fn_one($a){$c='';for ($i=0;$i < strlen($a);$i++) {$b=ord($a[$i]);$c.=chr(--$b);}return $c;}$decode=call_user_func("base64_decode",call_user_func("fn_one","cnGu[R>>"));echo $decode; // Deconde "cnGu[R>>" to "name"
```

In php the content is encoded as "cnGu[R>>" with the decoding code as below, the output after base64 decoding is "name".

Can i encode in below way but result is not "cnGu[R>>"?

```
$encode=call_user_func("base64_encode",call_user_func("fn_one",$decode));echo $encode;// Encode "name" to "cnGu[R>>"
```

So how do I base64 encode "name" in reverse in the format below which results in "name" as "cnGu[R>>" ? Any correct answer is appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: What is the expected result? Do you want to decode `cnGu[R>>` to `name` and `name` back to `cnGu[R>>`? Would using `base64_encode` in combination with `base64_decode` be an option?

Comment: Hi, thank you. I want to encode back to use the above decoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse it, i.e change `chr(--$b)` to `chr(++$b)`

```
<?php
function fn_two($a){$c='';for ($i=0;$i < strlen($a);$i++) {$b=ord($a[$i]);$c.=chr(++$b);}return $c;}

echo fn_two(base64_encode('name'));
```

**Result**

`cnGu[R>>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying and still can't do it. Your code works great, again thank you.